# Create List from List template in host web

Tags: list, sharepoint-hosted-app, list-template

How to create list from list template in Host Web?

I have created **SharePoint hosted app** and some how I managed to copy the list template file to host web's **list template gallery** . Now I want create list from that **list template** from my app web to the host web

Answer (score 0):

**(JSOM)** : add the following script to create the list.

```
//Add jquery version correctly   
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

<script type="text/ecmascript">

    function createList() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

        var listCreationInfo = new SP.ListCreationInformation();
        listCreationInfo.set_title('CustomList'); // list name
        listCreationInfo.set_description('description'); // list description
        listCreationInfo.set_templateType(SP.ListTemplateType.genericList); //list type

        oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),// when success
            Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed) // when failed
            );
    }
    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        alert("List Created");
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert("List Failed");
    }

</script>
```

Ref [Create a SharePoint 2013 List Using JSOM (ECMAScript Client Object Model)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560049/CreateplusaplusSharePointplus-plusListplusUsing)

**(CSOM)** :
Below is the code in which you have to send parameter :

- strSiteURL: Site URL on which you have to create List using template.
- strTemplateName: Template name of which you have to create list
- strListName: Name of the list.

  ```
  public void CreateListFromTemplate(string strSiteURL,string  strTemplateName,string strListName) {
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate

  {

  using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite(strDestinationURL))

  {

  oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

  using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())

  {

  oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

  SPListTemplateCollection lstTemp = oSPsite.GetCustomListTemplates(oSPWeb);

  SPListTemplate template = lstTemp[strTemplateName];

  oSPWeb.Lists.Add(txtListName.Text, "Description", template);

  Guid listId = oSPWeb.Lists.Add(txtListName.Text, "Description", template);

  SPList mylist = oSPWeb.Lists[listId];

  mylist.OnQuickLaunch = false;

  mylist.Update();

  oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

  }

  oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

  }

  });

  }
  ```

Ref : [Create List from Custom List Template Programmatically in SharePoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-list-from-custom-list-template-programmatically-in-sharepoint122)

Comment: What you have provided is done using CSOM, I want do it in JSOM

Comment: check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560049/CreateplusaplusSharePointplus-plusListplusUsing

Comment: Appriciate your efforts but I want to create list using existing template from list template gallery

Comment: at this line you can specify your template SPListTemplate template = lstTemp[strTemplateName];

Comment: The C# code is actually using server object model, not client.